# parabola distinct value of y for each x

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

[parabola image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBPY4.jpg)
The Image above says that for every value of x in that first parabola curve, There is a distinct value of y but I fail to understand how could that be when at almost every single point of y, there are 2 values of x, one is in negative and the other one is in positive. so y isn't distinct for every value of x. correct?

Please help me understand where or how I am wrong in this as the book can't possibly be wrong I think.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is referring to the first diagram, and it is saying that for each *x* value, there is a single *y* value. So if I asked you "When $x = 4$, what is $y$?", you would be able to give a single answer with no ambiguity. The text refers to the "vertical line test", which is simply "If you draw a vertical line on the graph, it will only ever intersect the curve once (if at all)". A curve that passes that test is a function.

The converse is not true, and I think that's what you're getting confused with - for each *y*, value, there is not necessarily a distinct *x* value, meaning that the parabola does not pass the *horizontal line test* which means that the parabola is not defined by a one-to-one (or injective) function.

Comment: hmm, you are right. I guess I assumed it meant y should be a unique value for every value of x overall whereas the words only meant that y should be distinct only for that particular value of x and not for every value of x.

Comment: Yeah, I think the wording was maybe a little ambiguous, but the reference to the vertical line test made it clearer for me what was meant.

Comment: true, thanks for the help. :) really appreciate it. :)